# await Task.Run taking longer than expected

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task-parallel-library

The method below is suppose to run for the (duration is milliseconds) being passed in for case 0:, but what I'm seeing is the method may take up to 2 seconds to run for a 400ms duration. Is it possible that Task.run is taking long time to start?  If so is there a better way?

```
private static async void PulseWait(int duration, int axis){
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        var logaction = true;
        switch (axis)
        {
            case 0:
                var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                if (duration > 0) duration += 20; // allowance for the call to the mount
                while (sw1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds <= duration) { } // wait out the duration
                _isPulseGuidingRa = false;
                logaction = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                var axis2Stopped = false;
                var loopcount = 0;

                switch (SkySettings.Mount)
                {
                    case MountType.Simulator:
                        while (!axis2Stopped && loopcount < 30)
                        {
                            loopcount++;
                            var statusy = new CmdAxisStatus(MountQueue.NewId, Axis.Axis2);
                            var axis2Status = (AxisStatus)MountQueue.GetCommandResult(statusy).Result;
                            axis2Stopped = axis2Status.Stopped;
                            if (!axis2Stopped) Thread.Sleep(10);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MountType.SkyWatcher:
                        while (!axis2Stopped && loopcount < 30)
                        {
                            loopcount++;
                            var statusy = new SkyIsAxisFullStop(SkyQueue.NewId, AxisId.Axis2);
                            axis2Stopped = Convert.ToBoolean(SkyQueue.GetCommandResult(statusy).Result);
                            if (!axis2Stopped) Thread.Sleep(10);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
                _isPulseGuidingDec = false;
                logaction = false;
                break;
        }

        var monitorItem = new MonitorEntry
        { Datetime = HiResDateTime.UtcNow, Device = MonitorDevice.Telescope, Category = MonitorCategory.Mount, Type = MonitorType.Data, Method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, Thread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, Message = $"PulseGuide={logaction}" };
        MonitorLog.LogToMonitor(monitorItem);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        _isPulseGuidingDec = false;
        _isPulseGuidingRa = false;
    }
});}
```

Log showing how time taken...
33652,2019:07:12:01:15:35.590,13,AxisPulse,Axis1,0.00208903710815278,400,0,True <<--line just before PulseWait is called with 400ms duration
33653,2019:07:12:01:15:35.591,13,SendRequest,:I1250100
33654,2019:07:12:01:15:35.610,13,ReceiveResponse,:I1250100,=
33655,2019:07:12:01:15:36.026,13,SendRequest,:I1B70100
33656,2019:07:12:01:15:36.067,13,ReceiveResponse,:I1B70100,=
33657,2019:07:12:01:15:36.067,13,SendRequest,:j1
33658,2019:07:12:01:15:36.120,13,ReceiveResponse,:j1,=DDCDBD
33659,2019:07:12:01:15:36.120,13,SendRequest,:j2
33660,2019:07:12:01:15:36.165,13,ReceiveResponse,:j2,=67CF8A
33661,2019:07:12:01:15:36.467,13,SendRequest,:j1
33662,2019:07:12:01:15:36.484,13,ReceiveResponse,:j1,=10CEBD
33663,2019:07:12:01:15:36.484,13,SendRequest,:j2
33664,2019:07:12:01:15:36.501,13,ReceiveResponse,:j2,=67CF8A
33665,2019:07:12:01:15:36.808,13,SendRequest,:j1
33666,2019:07:12:01:15:36.842,13,ReceiveResponse,:j1,=3CCEBD
33667,2019:07:12:01:15:36.842,13,SendRequest,:j2
33668,2019:07:12:01:15:36.868,13,ReceiveResponse,:j2,=67CF8A
33669,2019:07:12:01:15:37.170,13,SendRequest,:j1
33670,2019:07:12:01:15:37.188,13,ReceiveResponse,:j1,=6BCEBD
33671,2019:07:12:01:15:37.188,13,SendRequest,:j2
33672,2019:07:12:01:15:37.204,13,ReceiveResponse,:j2,=67CF8A
33673,2019:07:12:01:15:37.221,5,b__0,PulseGuide=False  <<--PulseWait is finished 1.631ms after start

Comment: As a note, you should never have `async void` methods (except for event handlers). Your `PulseWait` should be declared as `private static async Task PulseWait(...)` and be awaited when called. Since the whole method body is a single Task.Run call, you could also declare it as `private static Task PulseWait(...) { return Task.Run(() => { ... }); }`.

Comment: Have you tried including a debug of the elapsed time measured by `sw1` after the while loop on case 0: ? And also, declaring at the beginning of the try block so that you can also debug it after the switch case, to see its value? That might give you an idea on where it is taking longer than expected.

Comment: Aside from what @Clemens said it also depends on how you call this, from what kind of application etc. Try to create a [mcve] to demonstrate the core problem.

Comment: And that `while (sw.Elapsed <= ...)` loop is an eye-sore, it runs your CPU full out for nothing. Look up `Task.Delay()`.

Comment: I switched it to a static Task PulseWait with a return. I am logging (see edit) just before this and at the end (monitorItem) which is why I see it taking longer than expected.  Not sure I can demo the issue as I've only seen it happen on 1 laptop (from it's log). I thought of using Task.Delay but read the overhead could be 10-20ms, which accuracy is very important cause duration could be as small as 10 ms.

Comment: My guess is that the thread pool was taking too long but don't know how to test or validate this?

Comment: Maybe this logging should be placed outside your function or as an async on itself. Usually logging impacts on performance. If you `Console.WriteLine` this `sw1` variable just before and after this `MonitorEntry` part, to see whether or not the log is affecting your function?

Comment: `async` and `await` make things easy, and help overall performance (like increasing the overall throughput performance of a web app), but will actually hurt the performance of any one specific task. If every millisecond counts to you, you will need to do the low-level tasks yourself, like creating a [`Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread) (if this really needs to be run on a separate thread).

Comment: A new thread maybe with a blocking queue.  Wasn't sure if that would end up adding more overhead.

Comment: `Task.Run` will run your code on another thread anyway (it may or may not create one, depending on if there's one available). But then `async`/`await` adds the overhead of scheduling the continuation back to the original thread.

Comment: I didn't notice the `Thread.Sleep()` before, they should be `await Task.Delay()` as well. Sleep(), Delay() and the Thread scheduler all have a ~18ms resolution. If that's not good enough you're on the wrong OS.

Comment: But the 400/1600 ms difference needs another cause. That might be in other code than what you posted here. How many CPU's on that laptop and what is the utilisation?

Comment: Just trying to reduce overhead items.  Utilisation was first thought and yes there was a load from other sources. Could be a one time issue, but I have ideas now, thanks!

Comment: Thread.Sleep() is overhead, Task.Delay() is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `async` and `await` is to make things easy. But just like everything that makes things easy, it comes with a cost of having full control over what's going on. Here, it's really a cost of asynchronous programming in general. The point of asynchronous programming is to free up the current thread so that the current thread can go off and do something else. But if something else is done on the current thread, then the continuation of what you were doing must wait until that is done. (i.e. What comes *after* the `await` may not happen instantaneously after the task completes)

So while asynchronous programming will help *overall* performance (like increasing the overall throughput performance of a web app), but will actually hurt the performance of any *one* specific task. If every millisecond counts to you, you might be able to do the low-level tasks yourself, like creating a Thread (if this really needs to be run on a separate thread).

Here is a simple example that demonstrates this:

```cs
var s = new Stopwatch();

// Test the time it takes to run an empty method on a
// different thread with Task.Run and await it.
s.Start();
await Task.Run(() => { });
s.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Time of Task.Run: {s.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

// Test the time it takes to create a new thread directly
// and wait for it.
s.Restart();
var t = new Thread(() => { });
t.Start();
t.Join();
s.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Time of new Thread: {s.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
```

The output will vary, but it looks something like this:

```
Time of Task.Run: 8ms
Time of new Thread: 0ms
```

In an application with lots of other things going on, that 8ms could be much more if some other operation uses the thread during the `await`.

That's not to say that you *should* use `Thread`. [`t.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join) is not an asynchronous operation. It will block the thread. So if `PulseWait` runs on the UI thread (if this is a UI app), it will lock the UI thread, which is a bad user experience. In that case, you may not be able to get around the cost of using asynchronous code.

If this is *not* an application with a UI, then I don't see why you need to do all that on a different thread at all. Maybe you can just.... not do that.